# Not reading anything past scanf()

Tags: c

I am new to C and wondering why I am not getting any kind of output. I am trying to get my program to convert a hexadecimal number to binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* hex2binary(int hex_array[], int input_array_size, int* return_array_size) {
  int hex_size = input_array_size;
  int binary_array_size = 4 * hex_size;
  int *binary_array = (int*) malloc(binary_array_size * sizeof(int));
  int hex_index, binary_index;
  for (hex_index = 0; hex_index < hex_size; hex_index++) {
    int hex_num = hex_array[hex_index];
    binary_index = hex_index * 4;
    int bit_count;
    for (bit_count = 3; bit_count <= 0; bit_count--) {
      binary_array[binary_index + bit_count] = hex_num % 2;
      hex_num = hex_num / 2;
    }
    hex_index++;
  }
  *return_array_size = binary_array_size;
  return binary_array;
}

int main() {
  char baseString[11];
  int count = 0;
  int i, j;
  int original, wanted;
  int size;

  printf("Welcome to use this number base converter program.\n");
  printf("Please input the original base: ");
  scanf("%d", &original);
  printf("Please input a base-%d number with more more than 10 digits: ",
      original);
  scanf("%s", baseString);

  while (baseString[count] != '\0')
    count++;

  int *baseNumber = (int*) malloc(count * sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    baseNumber[i] =
        baseString[i] <= '9' ? baseString[i] - '0' : baseString[i] - 'A' + 10;
  }

  int* result_array;
  printf("Please input the target base: ");
  scanf("%d", &wanted); //doesn't read anything past this point
  printf("Target base: %d", wanted);

  if (original == 16) {
    if (wanted == 2) {
      result_array = hex2binary(baseNumber, count, size);
      for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        printf("Result: %d", result_array[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know it can't be something to difficult, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't even producing some kind of output.

Comment: First you should format/indent this mess.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf()`.  In this code, it is not `1` in any of the 3 `scanf()` calls, exit code with a corresponding error message.

Comment: Note; after `scanf("%d", &wanted);//doesn't read anything past this point`, code does not attempt to read more, so why expect it to?

Comment: `for (bit_count = 3; bit_count <= 0; bit_count--) {` is bad.  Should be `for (bit_count = 3; bit_count >= 0; bit_count--) {`

Comment: Presumably you get at least the "Welcome" message as output. So you get _some kind_ of output. What is the last output you get?

Comment: Launch the debugger and put a break point on `if (original==16)` and step from there.

Comment: `int size;`: uninitialised variable, used as argument to `hex2binary()` and in `for (j = 0; j < size; j++)` --> **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Any code that does not check the return value of `scanf` is **broken as designed** and should cost you half of your cred.

Comment: @user3386109 I am not quite sure what you mean by break point only started last week. 
Chux: With this it only converts the first 4 digits, ie input = FF gives 11110000 
DavidK: It was only print up to "Please input the target base: ", but it is now printing half of the converted number

Comment: A break point is a location in the code where you want the debugger to stop. After you launch the debugger, but before you hit "Run", you can mark locations in your code as break points. Then you tell the debugger to run the code. When the debugger reaches a break point, it will stop running the code, which then allows you to examine variables, and step through the code line by line. Learning how to use a debugger is invaluable to a new programmer, but typically requires some hands-on tutoring from a more experienced programmer.

Comment: Got it all sorted out, it was skipping the second digit because I was incrementing hex_index outside the for loop. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
result_array = hex2binary(baseNumber, count, size);
```

is incorrect because this function needs a pointer argument

```
int* hex2binary(int hex_array[], int input_array_size, int* return_array_size)
```

So it should be called like this

```
result_array = hex2binary(baseNumber, count, &size);   // note the &
```

Then the subsequent loop

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
```

will no longer be using the *uninitialised variable* `size`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed something like that, thanks :)